# Issue mounting NFS share using Apache Spark 3.1.1 running on Kubernetes 1.21

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, nfs

From a jupyter notebook I am creating a spark context which deploys spark on kubernetes. This has been working fine for some time. I am now trying to configure the spark context so that the driver and executors mount an nfs share to a local directory. Note the nfs share i am trying to mount has been in use for some time both via my k8 cluster as well as via other means.

According to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-kubernetes-volumes) and [release article for 3.1.x](https://spot.io/blog/apache-spark-3-1-release-spark-on-kubernetes-is-now-generally-available/) I should be able to modify my spark conf with options that are in turn passed to kubernetes.

My spark conf in this example is set as:

```
sparkConf.set(f"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.myshare.mount.readOnly", "false")
sparkConf.set(f"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.myshare.mount.path", "/deltalake")
sparkConf.set(f"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.myshare.options.server", "15.4.4.1")
sparkConf.set(f"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.myshare.options.path", "/deltalake")
```

In my scenario the nfs share is "15.4.4.1:/deltalake" and I arbitrarily selected the name myshare to represent this nfs mount.

When I describe the pods created when I instantiate the spark context I to not see any mounts resembling these directives.

```
# kubectldescribe <a-spark-pod>
...
Volumes:
  spark-conf-volume-exec:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      spark-exec-85efd381ea403488-conf-map
    Optional:  false
  spark-local-dir-1:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-947xd:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
```

I also do not see anything in the logs for the pod indicating an issue.

Update:

I missed a key line of the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-kubernetes-volumes) which states that drivers and executors have different configs.

> The configuration properties for mounting volumes into the executor pods use prefix spark.kubernetes.executor. instead of spark.kubernetes.driver.

The second thing I missed is that the docker container being used by the spark conf to provision the kubernetes pod which hosts the spark executors needs to have the software installed to mount nfs servers (ie run the command line utility to mount an nfs share). The spark integration solution will silently fail in the event that the nfs utils are not installed. If we describe the pod in this scenario, the pod will list an nfs volume and if we execute code on each executor to list the contents of the mount dir, the mount path will show an empty directory. There is not indication of the failure if we describe the pod or look at the logs of the pod.

I am rebuilding the container images and will try again

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things needed to get this to work:

1. The spark conf needs to be configured for the driver and executor
2. The nfs utils package needs to be installed on the driver and executor nodes
3. The nfs server needs to be active and properly configured to allow connections

There are a few possible problems:

1. The mount does not succeed (server offline, path doesn't exist, path in use)

As a workaround:

1. After the spark session is created, run a shell command on all the workers to confirm they have access to the mount and the contents look right.

Comment: What is NFS utils jar you refer to?